# Odoo 11 community - Use information from Sales Order field in invoice

Tags: odoo-11, odoo-view

we are using a rental module in odoo 11. While creating a sales order we have tenure information on the order/quotation and pro-forma.
But when moving to the account.invoice I can not display the information and I can not reference it in the QWeb from the account.invoice.document as there seems to be no connection between invoices and sales orders.

the code I'm trying to copy from report_saleorder_document

```
<!-- Lines associated -->
 <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
   <tr>
    <td><span t-field="l.name"/>
    <t t-if="l.rental_tenure != 0.0">
    <span t-field="l.rental_tenure"/>
    <span t-field="l.rental_uom_id"/>
    <span> for </span>
    <span t-field="l.price_unit" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': doc.pricelist_id.currency_id}"/>
    <span><strong> for rental</strong></span>
   </t>.......
```

in account.invoice_document i want to add the fields above with rental_tenure etc. under the following code as well:

````
    <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
     <td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>```

Any advice on how to achieve this just in Qwebs?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

versarthur

On the `Invoice Report` call the `function` which will link to `Sale Order`.
**XML**:

```
<t t-set="sale_order" t-value="o.get_sale_order_data()"/>
```

**PY**:

```
@api.multi
def get_sale_order_data(self):
    for rec in self:
        orders = self.env['sale.order'].search([(
            'order_line.invoice_lines.invoice_id', '=', rec.id)], limit=1)
    return orders
```

On the Report, you can take any of the `fileds` from `'Sale.Order'`.
Example:
`<span t-esc="sale_order.partner_id.name"/>`

Comment: Does the python method already exist or do i need to customise it into the module?

Comment: No that is the customize as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

In odoo 13 onward you need to:

- Inherit from account.move to create extra fields (if they don't already exist)
- Override the method _prepare_invoice

  ```
   def _prepare_invoice(self):
        values = super(SaleOrder, self)._prepare_invoice()
        values['field_name_in_account_move'] = self.field_source 
        return values
  ```